# Can we follow the EXACT SAME procedure to refresh linkedin oauth2 tokens that we used to generate them in the first place?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, token, authorize

Or in simple words, if I don't change my code at all and make user go through the same authorization process again, will I get the new access tokens irrespective of validity of old access tokens? And also if old tokens were not expired and I got same tokens back, will they now have 60 days extended validity? My question is not about how to refresh tokens, I want to know if I can use the code for generating the linkedin oauth2 tokens to refresh the tokens as well (I went through lots of forum posts on LinkedIn developer's site but it's very confusing).

Comment: I tried getting access tokens multiple times for same user and I got the same tokens with modified validity time as 60 days. So that answers one on the questions (about validity of old tokens if they are not expired yet). Still looking for a solution where tokens are expired.

Comment: I'd expect you can. Have you tried? What happens?

Comment: Yeah, even I guess it works. As I said in my earlier comment, I tried to went through the same authorization flow for tokens which were not expired (within 60 days) and I got same tokens back with new 60 days validity. I think the same will happen for tokens that are not valid (I am expecting to get NEW tokens with 60 days validity, but the SAME CODE would work anyway).

Comment: Aaah, you'd like the answer without waiting 60 days. I understand now.